# PIXATE - Tapping doesn't trigger any action on my prototype

Tags: prototype, modeling, pixate

I'm trying to make a basic animation based on a tap. It's simple as "tap button enter, fade the screen".

It's currently not working. Tapping actually works on other model prototypes, but I can't find the difference of what am I doing wrong. I'd really appreciate if somebody finds out what is the problem.

(First prototype using this software).

Here is the .pixate file: http://www119.zippyshare.com/v/xX8XrTtw/file.html

Answer (score 0):

It's fixed: I have to switch opacity of the button layers to at least 1% to make it work.